# How hard can I train during fasting?

Tags: intermittent-fasting, resistancetraining

How hard can I train during fasting, without diminishing training results too much?

I am mostly thinking of multi-day fasts, but also when I plan to fast in the morning or have calorie-deficit the day after.  (Not fasted training per se)

Should I look at special protocols with eg amino acids or Collagen?

What I often do, is to cut reps/set to 70-80% of max in my slightly eccentric resistance training program.  At the same time, I train more like circuit training, with intermixing exercises and shorter breaks.

I know the best, at least for fatloss, is to burn calories with minimum stress and damage, but I do this to maintain my level and "repeated-bout effect", so that I can train hard a few days later with little DOMS.

Comment: It's powerlifting specific, but here's a review of a powerlifter doing a rapid fat loss cycle - he kept intensity up, cut volume a lot, and focused his meals around his workouts - https://www.powerliftingtowin.com/rapid-fatloss-handbook-before-and-after-results-review/

Comment: Go nuts or go home... But on a serious note, push as hard as you can and try to not literally collapse due to glycogen depletion. It can happen, and you will feel dizzy for the rest of the day... You may even go momentarily blind.